# If you take/took a sunbath right now, you will/would get tanned quickly: which is correct in a context where it is at night?

Tags: conditionals

Which one is correct: Example 1 (first conditional) or Example 2 (second conditional)?

Although it is hot during the day outside, it is at night when A and B talk.

So, I don't know whether or not I should use the second conditional.

**Example 1:**

(A and B are talking at night)

> A: Recently, it is very hot during the day outside.

> B: If you **take** a sunbath right now, you **will** get tanned quickly.

**Example 2:**

(A and B are talking at night)

> A: Recently, it is very hot during the day outside.

> B: If you **took** a sunbath right now, you **would** get tanned quickly.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

"Take a sunbath" isn't idiomatic, since no actual bath, or bathlike object is involved.  The expression uses the verb "to sunbathe".

Note that even with water, to bathe does not require a bath.  You can bathe in the river, for example.  But if you are bathing in the river, you are not "taking a bath".

The use of "right now" doesn't make sense.  Since it is at night, and there is no sun!  So you shouldn't be talking about the present at all.  You can talk about a counterfactual past:

> It's been very hot recently.
>
> Yes, if you'd gone sunbathing, you would have got tanned quickly

Or you can talk about the future

> If you go sunbathing (tomorrow), you'll get tanned quickly.